# Apache mod_rewrite REST URL

Tags: php, apache, url, rest, mod-rewrite

Please help me with this one, which should be easy but I've never managed to properly learn Apache mod_rewrite's syntax...

I have a REST webservice implemented in PHP and I need to rewrite the following URL:

```
[1] http://www.myserver.com/service/ca;x={valx},y={valy},z={valz}
```

into

```
[2] http://www.myserver.com/service/ca.php?x={valx}&y={valy}&z={valz}
```

How to accomplish this?

I'm using Apache2 on Ubuntu, this is the configuration:

```
Alias "/service" "/opt/htdocs/service"
<Directory "/opt/htdocs/service">
  AllowOverride All
  Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks
</Directory>
```

and the content of my `/opt/htdocs/service` directory:

```
$>ls -1 /opt/htdocs/service

  ca.php
```

Mod_rewrite is enabled:

```
$>a2enmod rewrite

  Module rewrite already enabled
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Try putting this in your server/vhost config or the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/?service/ca;(.*)$ /service/ca.php?$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*),(.*)$
RewriteRule ^/?serivce/ca\.php$ /service/ca.php?%1&%2 [L]
```

Comment: Issuing a GET request to `http://www.myserver.com/service/ca;x=1,y=2,z=3` I get a 404 response code: `The requested URL /service/ca;x=1,y=2,z=3 was not found on this server.` :-(

Comment: @claudiosparpaglione Are these rules in the htaccess file in your document root? Is mod_rewrite turned on/loaded? Do you have other rules that conflict with these? Do you have `AllowOverride All` set somewhere in your config?

Comment: mod_rewrite is correctly enabled. I put your rules into an .htaccess file in the same directory as the .php script and the .htaccess contains only those. I've setup Apache to map the directory to an alias (`/service`) and the related `<Directory>` directive contains the `AllowOverride All`...

Comment: @claudiosparpaglione *"htaccess file in the same directory as the .php script"*, that is *not* the document root (my answer says you must put them there). If you can't put them there, then the rules need to modified. The document root is `/`. It's where you'd go to if you go to `http://www.myserver.com/`.

Comment: Oops, sorry, I missed that. I put the .htaccess into the document root but unfortunately, I've got the same 404. I will attach my Apache config as soon as I can